# How to dynamically add part of a where clause?

Tags: t-sql, parameters

I have a stored procedure.  I need to insert some text directly into the WHERE clause.  I really do not want to make the entire SQL statement a string and use macro substitution to execute it.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do below?

The text that starts with && in the where clause is what I want to insert.  The value of @DispositionText can be a lot of things.  It is supplied by someone else's program that I have to work with.  For example, the piece of code I'm tracing *right now* shows it to be this value:  **" and (Missing = 1)"**   But it can be any number of conditional checks that are out of my control.

```
    @AssetDesc varchar (30) = null,
    @DispositionText varchar(200) = null

...
    select *
       from Equipment
       where Equipment.Description = @AssetDesc 
       &&@DispositionText
       order by AssetDesc
```

Comment: This model poses a sql injection risk. If you haven't met [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/), now is the time.

Comment: Thanks.  What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following code and in the end use `EXEC()` as posted:

```
Declare @AssetDesc as varchar (30);
Declare @DispositionText as varchar(200);  
Declare @sqlCommand as varchar(1000);

SET @sqlCommand = 'select * from Equipment'
if(@AssetDesc <> NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand =  @sqlCommand + ' where Equipment.Description = ' + @AssetDesc;
    if(@DispositionText <> NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlCommand =  @sqlCommand + ' && ' + @DispositionText;
    END
End
Else if(@DispositionText <> NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand =  @sqlCommand + @DispositionText;
END

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

This approach is called [Dynamic SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/). Pay attention that it has that pitfall of being **vulnerable** against [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually simplified the SQL statement, and the entire stored procedure, tremendously.  And this is one of many SPs that will require reworking.  Is there perhaps a simpler way to do what I need?

Comment: @Brian your welcome! I don't know if there is any other way. Is it worth to be accepted as an answer?

Comment: Hey, Karam.  Certainly.  Would you mind if I left this open a while longer, just in case others want to leave their input?

Comment: @Brian Absolutely not! I would also like to know if there is any other solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

Variable `WHERE` clauses like this are always at risk for SQL injection, so one should be cautious in implementing them.

Dynamic SQL, as suggested by Karamofrooz, is usually the most expedient route, and the most dangerous, so be mindful of the [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

The other approach is to generate a "kitchen sink" or "catch all" query. Searching on either or both terms will chase up plenty of resources, but these two are a darned good start.

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

and

[#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)